# Is there a quick way to convert z-scores into percentile scores?

Tags: r, quantiles, pre-post-comparison

Does anyone know of a function or R package that can help me turn z scores into percentile scores?
The final goal is to classify or rank a group of respondents into four categories based on the heights of their z scores (20% lowest scores, 30%, 30%, 20% highest scores).

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: With what assumptions on the original scores? How are the values scaled - are the z-scores computed from sample mean and sample std deviation or from some known/assumed values?

Comment: The original scores are raw test scores before i normalized them by using scale(x)

Comment: Related: [Computing percentile rank in R](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11924/930).

Comment: chl, thanks! I initially missed that ont, but it turned out to be very helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pnorm(z)` will do it.

```
> pnorm(1.96)
[1] 0.9750021
> pnorm(0)
[1] 0.5
> pnorm(-1)
[1] 0.1586553
```

Or if you insist on a percentile, boom. Then try

```
round(pnorm(1.96)*100,0)
```

Comment: The usual 95% confidence interval is given by ``pnorm(1.96) - pnorm(-1.96)``  with result ``0.9500042``